# How to display/query the content of an embedded document in a collection using meteor code

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection named articles in Mongodb of Meteor, the article collection has an embedded document called References which itself has an embedded array document called Ref. The document looks like this :

```
{ "article":
         {
           "Section":
                 {
                  "Section-Title":
                       [{"key11":"value11"},"value12"],
                         "SSD":["value","value"]

                 }
            "References": 
                 {
                  "Ref": [
                         {  "key21":"value21",
                            "key22":"value22",
                            "key23":value23,
                            "key24":"value24"
                         },
                         {}
                        ]
                  }

           }
   }
```

I want to  display value24 of all articles, I first try to make sure I can display articles with key24= " aspecificrvalue".

**WHat I have tried:**

with the command line  on the meteor mongodb command line I got the correct articles which the ref .key24 is aspecificvalue using this command below:

```
db.articles.find({"article.References.Ref.key24":"aspecificvalue"})
```

I then tried to implement the above query but to have the result on my form in meteor client: for that asmy meteor application has 3 files: -article.html,    -articlesTemplate.html, -and articles.js

below is the content of each file,

**- articles.html**

```
<head>
    <title>Athena Project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Athena project</h1>
    {{>articlesTemplate}}

</body>
```

**-articlestemplate.html** file

```
<template name="articlesTemplate">
    <ul>

     <h3>List of available articles</h3>
     {{#each article}}

       {{>articlesInfo}}
      {{else}}
        there is nothing in articles database

     {{/each}}
    </ul>

</template>

<template name="articlesInfo">
    <br/>
    <li>
        <b>Key24 is:</b>{{article.References.Ref.Key24}}

    </li>



</template>
```

**- articles.Js** file :

```
    Articles = new Meteor.Collection("articles");
    if (Meteor.isClient) {

        Template.articlesTemplate.helpers({
      articlesTemplate: function() {

          return Articles.find({'article.References.Ref.key24':'aspecificvalue'});
       }
     });
     }


if (Meteor.isServer) {


  Meteor.startup(function ()
                 {

  });
}
```

**Result of my try:**

in my meteor form this code show "there is nothing in articles database" as if it is not reading nothing in my database,I am still new to meteor **Please help with how to display the content of an embedded document in a collection using  meteor code**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your helper function is named `articlesTemplate`, but in your template you're trying to call a helper called `article`. Try changing the helper name to `article`.

Comment: Also, your `articlesInfo` template should just use `{{References.Ref.key24}}` because the `{{#each}}` block changes the context to the article.

Comment: Thanks sbking, if I understand what you said ,  in my template function or articleTemplate.html file, when I do {{#each objecttoitterateto}}, the objecttoitterateto is the name of the template itself means should be {{#each articlesTemplate}} and not the 1st document name in the collection?

Comment: Also @sbking, the **article** in front of `.References.Ref.key24` represents the name of the main document in which the embedded document "References are " and not the collection  **articles** itself. in this case does your second suggestion still hold?. thanks in advance for your answer